# Find and filter array elements in mongo/meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have some documents like this:

```
{
  _id: "exampleid",
  email: "ex@example.pt",
  sites:[
    {
      _id: "site1",
      user: "user1",
      pass: "pass1",
      info: "info1",
      date: "date1"
    },
    {
      _id: "site2",
      user: "user2",
      pass: "pass2",
      info: "info2",
      date: "date2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And i want to perform a query that returns all the documents that are in the "site1", but only with the fields _id, user, info and date of that site, so i did this query:

```
collection.find({ "sites._id": "site2" },{ fields: { "sites.$": 1 } });
```

So basically i don't want the other sites to be returned but i also don't want the pass of that site to be returned, i tried this:

```
collection.find({ "sites._id": "site2" },{ fields: { "sites.$.pass": 0 } });
```

But it says that i can't exclude array elements with the positional operator, so i need to know how else can i remove the "pass" field from the results so that i can return all the documents still in a cursor but without the pass field.

Comment: You need to use `$filter` and `$map` in the aggregation framework to do this. Which means this would have to be server side code and not run from the browser. Standard projection does not allow that kind of modification to elements within an array.

Comment: I'm running this code on server side anyway, so i'll try with that, thanks